# iOS Simulator - partial swipe left with appium to view button

Tags: appium, appium-ios

[image]

Hi All,

I need to achieve partial swipe left to view button on right side.

I tried multiple solutions found here and official forum but all the resulting in tap action being triggered on the row.

None of them resulted in partial left swipe.

any idea how to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you might performing this swipe with end point located around that button/row you try to make visible?

If e.g. this row with a button is located lets say between 45%-50% of the height of the screen you need to perform this swipe below or above it on the background to not interact with the element itself during the swipe action which is a touch and move to action after all.